# If $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers such that $abc=1$ prove that $\frac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{c^3}{(c-b)(c-a)} ≥ 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a, b, c$ are distinct positive real numbers such that $abc=1$, prove that

$$\frac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{c^3}{(c-b)(c-a)} ≥ 3.$$

I tried to do this problem by assuming that $a<b<c$. By using this, the first and the third term of the inequality are positive and the second is negative. Thus, we can obtain the minimum value of the expression by minimizing the sum of the first and the third and maximizing the second. I'm stuck at this part and would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Does substituting $a = 1/(bc)$ help?

Comment: Look at the problem mentioned by Robert Z and use the indentity: $$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-a)(c-b)}=a+b+c$$

Comment: Show us your workings, @Arjun.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971523/tricky-inequality-no-avail-to-am-gm) might be a better duplicate target.

Answer (score 2):

As we know that $$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-a)(c-b)}=a+b+c$$

now apply A.M. G.M. 
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

given $$abc=1$$
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge 1$$
$$a+b+c\ge 3$$

replcae $a+b+c$ with your expression.

$$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-a)(c-b)}\ge 3$$